# Find Previous Class Name Using XPath

Tags: vba, xpath

I'm trying to find the previous text of an HTML Object using XPath.
I have list of elements

```
  //td[@class='steam']
```

and i want to find the previous element using XPath which is from this format `//tr[@class='parent']`.
But i have more elements from the format
`//td[@class='steam']`
so using something like
`(//td[@class='steam'])[i]/../../tr[@class='parent']`  will just work for the first element. And i want a format that works for everyone. Something like search for previous tr element with have classname 'parent'.
Can someone help me out? Thanks :)

[image: Example of problem]

Comment: Can you rely on the wanted `tr` element to not be an ancestor of the context node, as in the example, or do you need to account for the ancestor case, too?

Comment: All the tr parents that i want are always ancestors of the class steam that i want. But not always in the same order. For example, steam could have 5 more ancestors. And i want always get the previous parent shown in html

Comment: The problem is this: i want get the league name for each game. and i get the teams playing name and then "going back" in HTML to get the last class name parent which gets me the league name. https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=2&daym=tomorrow

Comment: Then I'm confused, @wsn.  In the example you present, it appears that the `tr` you want to select is *not* an ancestor of the node bearing attribute `class="stream"`, which I take to be the intended context node for evaluating the wanted XPath expression.

Comment: how we call a "brother" of the ancestor ? is something like that this `tr` to the attribute `class="stream"`

Comment: Are you MS XML?

Comment: I'm using selenium xpath to get my element

Comment: you could just loop all the trs and each time you have class parent set league variable to that value. Otherwise, you need to find previous sibling, singular, with parent class

Comment: @wsn, two nodes that have the same parent node are called "siblings" in XPath, but there is no special terminology or status for the sibling of an ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select from among nodes that precede the context node in document order but are not ancestors of the context node, then you want the `preceding` axis.  In particular,

```
preceding::tr[@class="parent"]
```

will select all `tr` elements appearing before the context node in document order, other than the context node's ancestors, that bear a `class` attribute with value `"parent"`.  That would include the indicated node in your example, supposing that the `td` with `class="stream"` is used as the context node.

If you want also to select ancestors of the context node that meet the criteria, then you want the `ancestor` axis, or possibly `ancestor-or-self`:

```
ancestor::tr[@class="parent"]
```

If you want both, then you can form the union:

```
preceding::tr[@class="parent"] | ancestor::tr[@class="parent"]
```

Comment: `preceding::tr[class="parent"]` should work if i wanted all `tr` elements appearing before. But in this particular example i want the last `tr` element that have `class` attribute with value `"parent"`

Comment: Then you should specify that in the question, @wsn.  But it might also turn out that an easier way to characterize (and express XPath for) what you are looking for could be discovered if you presented a fuller view of the document structure.

Comment: In any case, @wsn, if in fact you don't need to include ancestors of the context node in the selection, then you can add a node index predicate to select the nearest preceding node: `preceding::tr[@class="parent"][1]`.  The `preceding` axis is enumerated in reverse document order.